# Java Selenium-link missing field error warning to the field

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait

If you visit the site https://www.cleartrip.com and without filling out the fields click on Search Flight button you will get error. I can capture the error using:

```
//small[contains(text(),'You missed this')]
```

However I am not sure how to link this to the actual field. Can I do something like this `//input[@id='From']/child::small`?

Comment: You have to check for dynamic div for displaying error in an html page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get the fields showing the error as **You missed this** on [cleartrip.com](https://www.cleartrip.com/) you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and then create a *List* using *Java* `stream()` and `map()` as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class clearTrip_warning {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumUtilities\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.addArguments("start-maximized");
      options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
      options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
      driver.get("https://www.cleartrip.com/");
      new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#SearchBtn"))).click();
      List<String> myFields = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//small[contains(text(),'You missed this')]//preceding::input[2]"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("id")).collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(myFields);
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [FromTag, ToTag, DepartDate]
  ```

Comment: Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.